# Eclipse JSF editor configuration

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, ide

When I format my JSF markup in Eclipse (Indigo), I observed that fairly short lines of codes are broken into more lines.

Let me explain this issue using an example, just look at the following markup:

```
bgcolor="<h:outputText 
              value="#{formBean.colorPreferences.background}"/>"
text="<h:outputText 
           value="#{formBean.colorPreferences.foreground}"/>
```

The above markup has been broken into 4 lines (after formatting) but, I prefer the formatted markup to be as follows:

```
bgcolor="<h:outputText  value="#{formBean.colorPreferences.background}"/>"
text="<h:outputText value="#{formBean.colorPreferences.foreground}"/>
```

Is there any way to configure the Eclipse editor according to my preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to change the line width for the file type you're interested in to whatever you want:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor
```

And set Line width to whatever you'd like.